# Qt - tracking QAbstractAnimation movement

Tags: c++, qt

I have a mooving circle on the screen. It is declared in a class and it has three properties: a center, radiusX and radiusY.
I have the follwoing code:

```
m_ellipse.setVisible(true);
m_ellipse.setCenter(QPoint(30, 30));
m_ellipse.setRadiusX(40);
m_ellipse.setRadiusY(40);


QPropertyAnimation *animationCenter = new QPropertyAnimation(&m_ellipse, "center", this);
animationCenter->setStartValue(QPoint(30, 30));
animationCenter->setEndValue(QPoint(460, 540));
animationCenter->setDuration(3400);
animationCenter->start();
```

Is there a way to get the current position or change the basic center during the animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use the valueChanged signal:

```cpp
QObject::connect(animationCenter, &QPropertyAnimation::valueChanged, [](const QVariant &value){
    QPoint p = value.toPoint();
    qDebug() << p;
});
```

Comment: Wow! I would have never  figured this out  Thank you  !!

Comment: If I implement your solution in mousePressEvent can I refer to the event object from inside the  lambda function ?  I don't know why it doesn't recognize if I press the left button....